# Eliminar elementos duplicados en una lista

Tags: python, lista

Necesito buscar una forma lo más eficiente de eliminar duplicados de una lista en Python.

Yo lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
for i in mj:
    if i not in mj2:
        mj2.append(i)
```

Donde `kj` es una lista como `[2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9]` y la salida `mj2` es de la forma:

```
   [2, 4, 9]
```

Existe una forma más eficiente que no incluya bucles, ya que debo analizar grandes listas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es usar `set()`:

```
>>> mj = [2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9]
>>> mj2 = set(mj1)
>>> mj2
set([9, 2, 4])
>>> list(mj2)
[9, 2, 4]
```

Si quieres mantener el orden (ya que los [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) son una lista **desordernada** de elementos), puedes pasarle un `sort` al final:

```
>>> sorted(list(mj2))
[2, 4, 9]
```

---

Otra opción, si tu lista está originalmente ordenada y deseas mantener el orden, puedes usar la clase [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) y aprovecharla para mantener este orden:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(mj)
OrderedDict([(2, None), (4, None), (9, None)])
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(mj).keys()
[2, 4, 9]
```

`OrderedDict` es una implementación de los diccionarios que te permite "recordar" el orden en que sus elementos han sido insertados. Por lo tanto, puedes usar el método [`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) del diccionario para usar los elementos de `mj` como las llaves del diccionario, dado que los elementos de `mj` están previamente ordenados entonces el orden se mantiene.

Comment: @JorgePonti la lista está originalmente ordenada?

Comment: Genial muchas gracias!

Comment: vi lo de sorted() era lo que faltaba, así queda como quería, creo que esto debería ser mucho más eficiente que un "for"

Comment: Necesito que quede con orden creciente, con el "sorted()" basta y sobra

Comment: Gran solución @César. En el caso de usar `sorted()` no hace falta que conviertas el conjunto a una lista antes de ordenarla, directamente le puedes pasar el conjunto y te devuelve una lista ordenada: `sorted(mj2)`.

Comment: para referencia de la misma solución en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20870217/858913)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes probar que tal el rendimiento con la siguiente linea de código:

```
mj2 = sorted(set(mj))
```

aunque utilizar sorted capaz que consuma un poco de recurso.  Si no tienes problemas con el orden puedes utilizar como sigue:

```
mj2 = set(mj)
```

Answer (score 3):

Si la lista original es muy grande y está ordenada, es mucho más eficiente usar `itetools.groupby` que crea un iterador sin crear nuevas listas:

```
from itetools import groupby

mj2 = (k for (k,_) in groupby(m2))
```

Es posible obtener los primeros elementos sin necesidad de procesar toda la lista:

```
first = next(mj2)
second = next(mj2)
...
```

Comment: Gran solución @ChemaCortes. Otra forma de obtener la lista de los elementos sin repetir, usando `groupby`, sería: `mj2 = next(zip(*groupby(mj)))`

Comment: Es el extraño truco para hacer el `unzip` en python. Pero cuando haces `next` procesa toda la lista, no siendo igual de eficiente.

Comment: Sí, es cierto que no obtiene un *iterator*, sino una tupla. Pero como el OP pedía una lista, era otra forma de proceder usando la solución `groupby` que has propuesto.

Answer (score 1):

Para 'grupos' puedes hacerlo así también.

```
grupos= [['calculo', 1], ['calculo', 1], ['calculo', 1], ['Algebra', 5], ['Algebra', 5], ['Algebra', 5]]

grupos_sin_repetir = []
for i in grupos:
    if i not in grupos_sin_repetir:        
      grupos_sin_repetir.append(i)
    
print(grupos_sin_repetir)
```