# Depurar función para eliminar elementos duplicados de lista previamente ordenada

Tags: python

He estado trabajando en una aplicación simple en Python para ir practicando el lenguaje y conseguir soltura, pero me he encontrado con algo que me esta provocando dolores de cabeza...

El programa simplemente genera listas de tamaños aleatorios con números aleatorios, y claro, se pueden generar 2 o más veces el mismo número y la función que me ha estado dando problemas precisamente es esa, la de recorrer la lista y encontrar los valores repetidos y eliminarlos de la misma.

Lo que he escrito es lo siguiente:

```
import random
import time



def checker (x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        try:
            aux = x[i]
            equal= x[i+1]
        except:
            return x
        if aux ==  equal:
            try:
                filter(x.pop(equal),x)
            except:
                return x
        elif i == len(x):
            return x

def randomlist():
    alist = list()

    for n in range(1,randsize()):
        alist.append(randsize())
    return alist


def randsize():
    randn = random.randint(1,10)

   return randn


def fact(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * fact(x-1)


alist = randomlist()
print(alist) 
alist_sorted = sorted(alist)   
print(alist_sorted)  
checker(alist_sorted)

for i in alist_sorted:
    print("The factorial of {} is : ".format(i),fact(i))

print("Finished in {}s".format(time.process_time()))
```

La función en cuestión es `checker`, he intentado depurar de todas maneras, pero cuando arreglo un error me salta otro, por ejemplo si el programa genera una lista como esta `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]` el programa solo quita un número repetido (un uno de los tres que hay) y no los 2, o otra lista como esta 
`[4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]` en la que directamente no quita ningún número.

La verdad es que no veo la forma de arreglar este bug tonto, me ayudaríais bastante aclarando en que he fallado, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Primero, no se como estás generando los números aleatorios pero hay formas muy simples de evitar duplicados. Segundo posiblemente la forma más eficiente de eliminar duplicados de una lista es usar un conjunto (no preserva el orden) o `collections.OrderedDict` si queremos preservar el orden. Para Python >=3.6  se pueden usar diccionarios "normales" (`dict`), ver esta pregunta: [Eliminar elementos duplicados en una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/87813/15089)

Comment: no entiendo cual es el objetivo de la funcion quizas puedas se mas explicito en lo que que quieres,  corrigeme si es estoy mintiendo ->> lo que deseas es  que a la funcion tu le pasas una lista con valores repetidos o no repetidos y esta funcion los elimina eso es lo que te entiendo de ser asi hay maneras de eliminar los valores repetidos en una lista una manera de hacer eso es con **set()** la cual te retorna un dicionario sin repetidos luego ese diccionario lo conviertes en una lista y te quedaria de la siguiente manera: **list(set(x))** donde **x** es la listata que deseas reemplazar

Comment: Ralph  el gran error es que creo que has malentendido el uso de `filter`, porque tal y como la usas no hace absolutamente nada, lo único que hace algo es la llamada a `pop`. Viendo tus ejemplos **¿Se puede asumir que las listas están siempre ordenadas?** Si es así creo que se lo que intentas (aunque no tienes en cuenta que iteras sobre una lista que modifica su tamaño durante la iteración), en caso contrario me pierdo, ya que `x[i] == x[i+1]` carecería de sentido....

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias a ti me siento bien por haberme dado cuenta de gran error y mal por otra parte porque me olía que el fallo que estaba teniendo era un tanto estúpido con fácil solución. De todas formas gracias a los 2, voy a editar el código de un principio para mostrar el programa completo (con algunos añadidos que le he hecho, innecesarios pero bueno)

Comment: @NEFEGAGO A ti tampoco te quito mérito jejeje

Comment: Vale, si la ordenabas previamente... dado que el rango de posibles valores aleatorios que puede contener la lista es pequeño una forma muy simple de obtener una lista de longitud aleatoria (entre 1 y 10 elementos) poblada de enteros entre 1 y 10 (incluidos) sin repeticiones es `lista = random.sample(range(1, 11), k=random.randint(1, 10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yendo al grano, tu problema está en ésta linea:

```
checker(alist_sorted)
```

Ya que la definición de la función ´checker()´ devuelve una lista sin duplicados (supuestamente) vos estás ignorando esa lista. Lo que deberias hacer es:

```
alist_sorted = checker(alist_sorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente el objetivo de la función `checker` es eliminar los duplicados de una lista de enteros previamente ordenada en orden ascendente. Bajo esta premisa vamos a ver si aclaramos las causas de su fallo.

Primero de todo, algunas observaciones:

- Para eliminar duplicados eficientemente de una lista mejor ver la siguiente pregunta y sus respuestas:

  [Eliminar elementos duplicados en una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/87813/15089)

  La finalidad de esta respuesta no discutir sobre los métodos más eficientes para tal fin.
- Aunque el manejo de excepciones es común en Python, no significa que sea siempre una buena solución, la más eficiente y mucho menos convertirse en una norma. En este caso se usa el manejo de excepciones para protegerse del indexado sobre un índice inválido, ya que tenemos toda la información necesaria para evitar un `IndexError` mejor evitar que el algoritmo genere tal excepción.
- Dado que `pop` actúa sobre la propia lista, voy a asumir que se intenta eliminar duplicados *in-place*. Con esto en mente, si una función o método actúa *in-place* sobre un objeto (además de documentarlo correctamente) **nunca debe a la vez retornarlo**.
- Hay formas de evitar directamente que la lista tenga duplicados. Por ejemplo, dado que el rango de valores destinados a poblar la lista es pequeño (enteros del 1 al 10), usar `random.sample` es una opción muy simple:

  ```
  import random
  lista = random.sample(range(1, 11), k=random.randint(1, 10))
  ```

La idea bajo la función es en realidad sencilla, dado que tenemos la lista ordenada, iteramos sobre ella comparando un elemento con el siguiente, si son iguales eliminamos todos los duplicados antes de pasar al siguiente índice. Antes de ver por qué no funciona es importante aclarar el funcionamiento de `list.pop` y `filter`:

- **`list.pop(i)`**: elimina y retorna el elemento en el **índice `i`** de la lista. Si no se le pasa `i`, elimina y retorna  el último elemento de la misma.
- **`filter(funcion, iterable)`**: básicamente lo que hace es iterar sobre el iterable, llamar a la función por cada item del mismo y  quedarse solo con aquellos elementos para los que la función le retorna `True`. Si `funcion` es `None` se asume la función identidad y se queda solo con los elementos que son evaluados como ciertos (escalares diferentes de 0, iterables no vacíos, etc). Por lo tanto, la función a de recibir un argumento y en base a él retornar un booleano.

  En Python 2 retorna una nueva lista con los elementos que pasan el filtro, en Python 3 retorna un objeto `filter`, un iterable. En ningún caso modifica el iterable original.

  Por ejemplo, si queremos quedarnos con los números impares de una lista podemos hacer lo siguiente:

  ```
  >>> def es_impar(n: int) -> bool:
  ...     return n % 2 != 0
  ... 
  >>> lista = [1, 8, 5, 2, 13, 7, 4, 6]
  >>> lista_filtrada = list(filter(es_impar, l))
  >>> lista_filtrada
  [1, 5, 13, 7]
  ```

  Por si una aproximación no funcional aclara lo que hace `filter`, básicamente el caso concreto anterior "equivale" a:

  ```
  lista_filtrada = []
  for elemento in lista:
      if es_impar(elemento):
          lista_filtrada.append(elemento)
  ```

  o usando list comprehensions:

  ```
  lista_filtrada = [elemento for elemento in lista if es_impar(elemento)]
  ```

Entonces ¿Qué falla en la función?

Como se ha dicho `filter` recibe una función como primer argumento (cualquier "callable" en realidad), si le pasamos `x.pop(equal)` lo que le estamos pasando es el retorno del método ya que estamos llamándolo, es decir, le pasamos el valor del item  con índice `equal` que acaba de ser eliminado de la lista, un entero. En resumen **`filter` no hace absolutamente nada**, `filter(x.pop(equal), x)` es lo mismo en cuanto a resultado que `x.pop(equal)`, excepto porque en Python 2 genera un `TypeError`.

Lo anterior si es que el indice pasado a `pop` existe, porque en todo caso **deberíamos pasar la variable `i` a `pop` (el índice del elemento) no `equal` (su valor)**. Por lo tanto, `filter(x.pop(equal), x)` o termina con un `IndexError` sin hacer nada porque `pop` recibe un índice inválido o elimina un solo elemento de la lista (el situado en la posición `equal`, que puede no ser `equal` o un duplicado de este...).

Si tenemos suerte elimina un solo duplicado, por ejemplo en el caso de `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`, la primera iteración compara `x[0] == x[1]` (1 == 1) y da la casualidad que el índice 1 apunta a un elemento con valor 1, por lo que queda `[1, 1, 2, 3]` después de `x.pop(1)`, la siguiente iteración falla porque solo se ha eliminado un elemento pero avanzamos con el índexado una posición, siendo la comparación `x[1] == x[2]` (1 == 2). Esto, si tenemos suerte, porque `[4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]` compara en la primera iteración `4 == 4` y llama a `x.pop(4)` lo que produce `[4, 4, 4, 5, 7]`, hemos matado al pobre 6 que nada había hecho, pero aquí no acaba la cosa, en la siguiente iteración se compara `x[1] == x[2]` (4 == 4) y volvemos a llamar a `x.pop(4)` y al final la función retorna `[4, 4, 4, 5]`...

En realidad la idea en general es correcta, es la implementación la que falla, `filter` no es apropiada para esto, no si queremos eliminar los duplicados en la propia lista (y si queremos retornar una nueva, no se me ocurre una forma que no sea fea e ineficiente usando `filter`...). Por ejemplo podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
def eliminar_duplicados(x: list) -> None:
    '''
    Elimina los elementos duplicados de una lista previamente ordenada
    '''
    i: int = 0     
    for _ in range(len(x) - 1):
        if x[i] == x[i + 1]:
            del x[i]
        else:
            i += 1
```

> ```
> >>> l = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 13]
> >>> eliminar_duplicados(l)
> >>> l
> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
> ```

Dos apuntes, se podría usar `pop` en vez de `del`, pero dado que no necesitamos el objeto eliminado de la lista no tiene sentido. Por otro lado,  que la lista esté ordenada nos permite que el número de iteraciones para eliminar todos los duplicado sea conocido y es igual al número de elementos de la lista menos uno. Es `len(x) - 1` porque lógicamente el último elemento no hay con quién compararlo y evita el consecuente `IndexError`.