# Unir dos listas de listas sin repetición de elementos

Tags: python

Buenas el problema es el siguiente, tengo una lista de listas:

```
nombre=[[madrid,salamanca,oviedo,sevilla],[lugo,coruña,madrid,murcia]]
```

Y necesito tener:

```
final=[madrid,salamanca,oviedo,sevilla,lugo,coruña,murcia]
```

Es decir, una única lista sin repetición de elementos.

La verdad es que le ha dado un montón de vueltas y llego a soluciones parciales
Mil gracias.

Comment: Hola, considera agregar siempre tu código a la pregunta, así demuestras investigación previa y hay algo sobre lo que basar las respuestas. Eliminar duplicados eficientemente por lo general implica usar conjuntos (`set`) o `collections.OrderedDict` / `dict` (Python >= 3.7) si quieres preservar el orden. ¿tienes alguna restricción sobre lo que puedes usar? ¿Puedes importar y usar módulos de la biblioteca estándar? ¿Te importa que se conserve el orden? Es decir ¿`final=["salamanca", "sevilla", "oviedo", "madrid", "murcia", "lugo", "coruña"]` te valdría como salida también por ejemplo?

Comment: La pregunta es realmente casi un duplicado de [Eliminar elementos duplicados en una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/87813/15089) con la excepción de que en tu caso necesitas aplanar la lista.

Comment: Hola,  gracias por los comentarios.  No necesito mantener el orden en este caso. Pude  resolver inicialmente el problema como lo hizo Julio Cesar, pero prefería no tener que crear más listas. Intenté utilizar algo que quedara más compacto (probé funciones lambda, zip, sets), pero no me dabas el resultado que se esperaba.

Comment: @FJSevilla en este caso no puedo importar módulos. Como te comento en el mensaje anterior no preciso que estén ordenadas y tampoco me gustaría tener que crear varias listas. No sé si es poible hacerlo de una forma un poco más compacta. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentaba en la pregunta y como muestra @abulafia en su respuesta, generalmente la forma más eficiente de eliminar duplicados de un iterable es usar conjuntos/diccionarios por dos razones:

- No repeticiones de items (conjuntos) / claves (diccionarios).
- Son muy eficientes a la hora de buscar y comprobar si un determinado elemento/clave un elemento está contenido en ellos (tablas `hash`).

La única posible pega es que se crea un contendor temporal (el conjunto/diccionario), aunque dado que **son significativamente más eficientes en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución** y que la memoria extra usada no es tan importante (en el fondo solo almacenas un conjunto de referencias), no suele ser realmente un problema en la mayoría de casos a no ser que debamos cuidar mucho el uso de RAM por alguna razón y no nos importe tanto el tiempo de CPU.

Siendo totalmente cierto lo anterior, se puede hacer lo mismo sin crear absolutamente ninguna estructura más que la lista resultado usando un simple `for` y el operador de pertenencia `in`. Por culpa de éste último, dado que las búsquedas en listas son menos eficientes y que en caso de no existir el item se tiene que iterar sobre toda la lista, esta aproximación es más lenta (`list.append` también influye), sobretodo para listas grandes con pocos duplicados dónde el tiempo de ejecución y uso de cpu puede incrementarse mucho con respecto al uso de conjuntos. Eso si, es la opción que menos memoria va a usar (quitando las fórmulas inplace) y mantiene el orden original:

```
cities = [
          ['madrid', 'salamanca', 'oviedo', 'sevilla'],
          ['lugo', 'coruña', 'madrid', 'murcia']
         ]

result = []
for cities in cities_set:
    for city in cities:
        if not city in result:
            result.append(city)

print(result)
```

> ```
> ['madrid', 'salamanca', 'oviedo', 'sevilla', 'lugo', 'coruña', 'murcia']
> ```

---

Dicho esto, aunque no es una respuesta para la pregunta dado que no te dejan usar módulos de la biblioteca estándar, voy a completar un poco la respuesta de abulafia por si a otros usuarios les es de ayuda:

La forma más eficiente de usar un conjunto para eliminar los duplicados si estamos tratando con listas relativamente grandes es usar `itertools.chain.from_iterable` para generar un iterador que permite aplanar la lista y pasarla a `set()`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> result = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cities_set)))
>>> ['lugo', 'salamanca', 'murcia', 'sevilla', 'madrid', 'oviedo', 'coruña']
```

Si se quisiera mantener el orden original al eliminar los duplicados podemos recurrir a un diccionario en Python >= 3.7 (3.6 realmente también, pero el orden en los diccionarios se considera un efecto colateral de la implementación en esta versión):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> result = list(dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cities_set).keys))
>>> ['madrid', 'salamanca', 'oviedo', 'sevilla', 'lugo', 'coruña', 'murcia']
```

en Python < 3.7 debemos usar `collections.OrderedDict` en su lugar, ya que los diccionarios no mantienen el orden de inserción.

Algunas test de tiempo de ejecución para listas relativamente grandes (2000 sublistas):

```
%%timeit
result = []
for city in itertools.chain.from_iterable(cities_set):
    if not city in result:
        result.append(city)
```

> ```
> 573 µs ± 9.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

```
%%timeit
result = list({ city  for cities in cities_set for city in cities })
```

> ```
> 301 µs ± 9.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

```
%%timeit
result = list(dict.fromkeys(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cities_set)).keys())
```

> ```
> 268 µs ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

```
%%timeit
result = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cities_set)))
```

> ```
> 181 µs ± 801 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
> ```

Puede sorprender que la diferencia entre usar `for` anidados con `in` y  `list.append` y las otras opciones no sea tan significativa. Esto se debe a que la lista final contiene pocos items (hay muchas repeticiones), cuantas menos repeticiones existan mayor será el tiempo de ejecución dado que al usar `in` se buscará en una lista mayor (más iteraciones) pudiendo llegar a ser contraproducente en estas situaciones.

Puede observarse como para listas grandes `itertools.chain` es considerablemente más eficiente. Para listas muy pequeñas como es el caso de la pregunta, `itertools.chain` no es tan útil dado que la ventaja que da al iterar se pierde por la sobrecarga de llamar a la función. Para la lista de la pregunta, los tiempos de ejecución en el mismo orden que antes son:

> ```
> # for andiados + in + list.append 
> 1.11 µs ± 9.95 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)  
>
> # list + "conjunto por compresión"  
> 869 ns ± 12.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) 
>
> # dict + itertools.chain (mantiene orden)   
> 1.15 µs ± 12.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) 
>
> #  set + itertools.chain
> 877 ns ± 13.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Una línea:

```
result = list({ city  for cities in cities_set for city in cities })
```

Explicación:

He usado una expresión generadora entre llaves, del estilo de `{ expr for elem in list }`. El concepto es el mismo que el de *comprensión de listas*, pero al usar llaves en lugar de corchetes el resultado es un conjunto en lugar de una lista. Los conjuntos detectan si un elemento ya está en él, y lo guardan sólo una vez. De este modo se eliminan duplicados. Por otro lado, para "aplanar" la lista he tenido que hacer un bucle anidado dentro de la expresión generadora.

Básicamente la expresión se lee así:

> Crea un conjunto cuyos elementos vas tomando de las listas `cities`, las cuales son elementos de la lista `cities_set`

Después encierro todo ello en `list()` para convertir el conjunto resultante en una lista, ya que en la pregunta solicitas obtener una lista. Realmente este paso puede no ser necesario según qué quieras hacer luego con el conjunto. Por ejemplo, para recorrerlo en un bucle no haría falta, o para ordenarlo alfabéticamente (`sorted(conjunto)`, aunque el resultado de esto sería una lista, porque los conjuntos no tienen orden interno). Sí que necesitarías que fuese una lista si fueras a acceder a alguno de sus elementos por su índice (el conjunto, al no tener orden interno, no tiene índices para sus elementos).

Demostración:

```
>>> cities_set = [['madrid','salamanca','oviedo','sevilla'], ['lugo','coruña','madrid','murcia']]
>>> result = list({ city  for cities in cities_set for city in cities })
>>> result
['murcia', 'oviedo', 'madrid', 'lugo', 'sevilla', 'salamanca', 'coruña']
```

### Bonus

Con un ligero cambio puedes hacer que el resultado sea insensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas y te deje el caso de todas las ciudades consistente, por ejemplo con la primera en mayúsculas y el resto en minúsculas (usando `str.title()`):

```
>>> cities_set = [['madrid','salamanca','oviedo','sevilla'], ['LUGO','Coruña','MADRID','Murcia']]
>>> r = list({ city.title()  for cities in cities_set for city in cities} )
>>> r
['Oviedo', 'Salamanca', 'Sevilla', 'Coruña', 'Lugo', 'Murcia', 'Madrid']
```